# How is the verb "werden" used? "will" or "will be"?

Tags: verb-usage, auxiliary-verb

I started self-learning German recently, so this will be clearer someday. But I'm curious, so I'm asking it here now.
When I use Google Translate, I get the following translations:

> 1. It will grow colder. => Es wird kälter.
> 2. It will be colder => Es wird kälter sein.

In sentence 1, *wird* means *will grow* or *wird* here has both the function of auxiliary verb (=*will*) and the main verb (=*grow* or *become*).
But in sentence 2, *wird* functions as pure auxiliary verb (=*will*) and there is the separate main verb *sein* (=*to be*).
When is *werden* used as *will* and when is it used as *will be*?

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit more clear. However, I had to guess a couple of times. For example, when you talked about the first sentence, you already mentioned "to be" which doesn't appear in your first sentence. So, I assume that you actually already knew that "will" can be auxiliary and main verb. — If any of my changes doesn't apply to your intent, please correct it; or feel free to rollback my change altogether.

Comment: Besides, "will be" is never translated as plainly "werden". And your example sentence translates it as "wird sein". So, I'm not sure why you mention that in the title (where I didn't fix it) and in the body (where you mentioned it in reference to sentence 1 which doesn't have the idea of "to be" in both the English and the German sentence).

Comment: In sentence 1, wird means 'will become', in sentence 2, it means just 'will'.I'm not still sure if 'werden' itself can be used 'will be'. and I'm not a student :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your translation isn't quite right:

> It will grow colder

translates to

> Es wird kälter werden (1)

(Future tense)

*Es wird kälter* translates to "It is growing colder" (2)

(Present tense, continuous form in English)

"Werden" can be a full verb translating into *to grow* or *to become* or an auxiliary that is used to build the future tense. Which is which can be found by the presence of an infinitive ("werden" or "sein" in your example).

Comment: I understand. But If "Werden" can be a full verb with future meaning, can't we just write "Es wird Kälter" ? Is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: @ChanKim: Read the answer again. `Es wird kälter` is grammatically correct, but has a different meaning. Also `kälter` is not written with a capital `K`.

Comment: I see. I'll understand it as "weden" has two functions. auxihilary verb "will" and simple verb "become(or is getting)". We can combine two werden to make (redundantly) "will become". :)

Answer (score 1):

The verb *to grow* has the meaning of *to become*. And since *to become* is translated as *werden*, that is also a good translation for *to grow*.

Now, with that being said, the first sentence would be translated as

> Es wird kälter werden.

But you can omit the idea of *to will*. In a verbatim sense, you say "It grows colder", then.

Note, however, that the reverse translation "Es wird kälter" could also be "It's growing colder" which has a slightly different meaning. So, context might be important.

For example:

> Der Wetterbericht sagt, dass es kälter (werden) wird.
>     => It will grow colder.
>     Note, using *werden* is uncommon.
>
> Uhhh, frisch ist es heute. Es wird spürbar kälter.
>     =>  It's growing colder.

Comment: Yes now I think I understand it. So to speak weden has the meaning of "will" and "become". Of course we can use it twice to make it "will become". Isn't this correct? I checked it up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *werden* is an interesting one. It can be both a full verb meaning *to become* or it can be an auxiliary verb used to indicate future tense.

In the first of your two examples, the *meaning* of the English verb is comparable to *to become.* Hence, one can use the full verb *werden* to phrase this in German.

> It’s growing colder → Es wird kälter.

In the second of your examples, the machine translation used *werden,* the auxiliary, to indicate future tense much like the auxiliary *will* in English.

> It will be colder → Es wird kälter sein.

The key here is that the machine translation — while undoubtedly generating correct German sentences — decided to render the English future tense differently in both examples. English is relatively strict when it comes to using future tense: if the topic of the sentence is something in the future, future tense should be used except in rare examples when present tense is permissive. French is even stricter and future tenses are *always* used when talking about the future (but in French the future tense is not an auxiliary-dependent tense but generated by inflection; if an inflected tense exists for a certain direction of time the language will probably require using it, as a very general rule).

In German, however, the aspect of *future* is typically encoded semantically and not grammatically. An adverbial of time signifying some point in the future (e.g. *morgen, tomorrow),* a verb that from its meaning alone already points into the future or any other semantic clue that we are talking about the future is sufficient to encode the information *future* — future tense is used rather rarely.

Let’s take another look at the two German sentences. *Werden* — the full verb — means *to become* i.e. it indicates a process that starts at a given point and ends at a different point. If used in present tense, the starting point could be anywhere (past, present or future) but *the end point will always be in the future.* Thus, simply by our choice of verb we have encoded the information *future* into our sentence and marking the future tense by using *werden,* the auxiliary, is not necessary (but permitted!). (If the end point were a point in the past or at present, past tense of *werden,* the full verb, would be used.)

*Sein,* however, indicates a status that is typically interpreted to be ongoing. Without any additional semantic information, the present tense of *sein* is indeed assumed to be present. Hence, if you only have the information present in the English original and want to preserve the information that you are speaking about the future, *sein* **must** be in future tense by using the auxiliary *werden.* However, if you decide to use any other information that encodes *future* (see example below) you can again skip back to present tense.

> Tomorrow it will be colder. → Morgen ist es kälter. (less common)
>
> Tomorrow it will snow. → Morgen schneit es. (more common)

(During the process of writing this up, I realised what a good job the translation machine did with these sentences.)

I mentioned above that encoding future by tense is unnecessary when dealing with something semantic that indicates future. It is, however, possible and sometimes used to emphasise the future aspect. For example, it is *not wrong* (and even sufficiently common) to use *werden* in future tense in the first sentence:

> Es wird kälter werden.

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation. So I understand, to be exact, 'werden' translates grammatically to 'will' or 'become' of English.